# Why does a Java enum refer to itself as its "name" not its "value" like in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, enums

Disclaimer: I'm new to Java and Kotlin enums.

In Java 9+, if I do this:

```java
enum Animal {
    DOG("woof"), CAT("meow");
    public String sound;

    Animal(String sound) {
      this.sound = sound;
    }
}

class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Animal> foo = List.of(Animal.DOG, Animal.CAT);
        System.out.println(Animal.values());
}
```

...and then set a breakpoint on the `println()`, my IntelliJ IDEA debugger shows that each enum element calls itself (e.g., `{Animal@448}`) by its "name" not its "value" (sound).

```
foo = {ImmutableCollections$List12@444} size =2
  0 = {Animal@448} "DOG"
     sound = "woof"
     name = "DOG"
     ordinal = 0
  1 = {Animal@449} "CAT"
     sound = "meow"
     name = "CAT"
     ordinal = 1
```

But when I try similar code using okhttp.Protocol (an enum written in Kotlin), I see the opposite happen: each element refers to itself (e.g., `Protocol@566`) using the "value" (protocol) instead of the "name":

```java
import okhttp3.Protocol;

class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Protocol> foo = List.of(Protocol.HTTP_1_0, Protocol.HTTP_1_1);
        System.out.println(Animal.values());
}
```

...which you can see as follows:

```
foo = {ImmutableCollections$List12@562} size =2
  0 = {Protocol@566} http/1.0
    protocol = "http/1.0"
    name = "HTTP_1_0"
    ordinal = 0
  1 = {Protocol@567} http/1.1
    protocol = "http/1.1"
    name = "HTTP_1_1"
    ordinal = 1
}
```

How can I make Java use the "value" like in Kotlin? For reference, here's the relevant Kotlin "primary constructor":

```kotlin
enum class Protocol(private val protocol: String) {
  /**
   * An obsolete plaintext framing that does not use persistent sockets by default.
   */
  HTTP_1_0("http/1.0"),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [source code of Protocol](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/commonMain/kotlin/okhttp3/Protocol.kt#L104), you can see that they overrode `toString()`:

```
override fun toString(): String = protocol
```

You can do this in Java enums as well:

```java
enum Animal {
    DOG("woof"), CAT("meow");
    public String sound;

    Animal(String sound) {
      this.sound = sound;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return sound;
    }
}
```

Comment: geez. it's so easy when explained so nicely. thank you!